# Eloquent select where($value) issues

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying make select in eloquent:

```
$query = $query->where($value);
```

echo $value is:

```
´column´, ´<´, ´3´
```

BUT i have error: Unknown column ''column', '=', '3'' in... (look at quotation mark). If i write directly:

```
$query->where( ´column´, ´<´, ´3´);
```

Everything is okay

Answer (score 2):

`where()` wants at least two arguments, but for the way you're using it it will need three.  `where('column', '<', $value)` where `$value` is 3.

References:

- http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres
- http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Query.Builder.html#268-324

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->first();
$users = DB::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->get();
```

`Where()` required at least `two` parameters but it will accept `three` parameters.

Two parameters are compulsory:

1. table column name
2. compare value

in your example, you have only passed one parameter and will be consider as a table column name. obviously it will not match with the column name.

However, if you provide 3 parameters, ensure that you place the `value` parameter as 3rd parameter.

**More:**

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects